# MS reporting services limiting number of rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a report working well where I extract the number of logins per user. Each login takes up one row on the report.
I have date parameters and my DB goes back a year. However it seems the report will only show 40/50 rows despite a report expecting to deliver, say, 250 for the amount of times I logged in.

Is there some setting in reporting services that limits the number of rows delivered. Can't find it anywhere..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question: nope, as far as I know there's no real equivalent of SQL's `TOP 50` statement in SSRS itself.

---

Some things that come to mind that may be causing your symptoms / can be investigated:

- What happens if you run the query for the dataset in SSMS? Be sure to fill in the exact parameters the report's using (if any).
- Run the query as a test from SSRS designer. If you're using Visual Studio: right-click the dataset and hit "Query...", then hit the red exclamation mark and fill in any parameters if needed.
- Try putting a `CountDistinct` call (on your dataset) in a textbox somehwere in the report, by itself.
- Check the *filtering* and *grouping* on your tablixes, perhaps even by looking at the XML source code for the RDL.
- Show the parameters in textboxes (oldskool printf debugging! :D) to make sure they're what you expect them to be when the report's run on the Report Server. If they're not: try deleting the report on the server and re-deploying it.
- Have a look at the [ExecutionLog2 View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) in the ReportServer database, specifically the Number of Rows returned.
- As mentioned in the comments by Atilla: You may also monitor exact SQL SSRS sends to server using SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: You may also monitor exact SQL  SSRS sends to server using SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Aye good suggestion! Added it, as well as another suggestion on ExecutionLog2.